# How to join two data frames base on multiple conditions?

Tags: r, join

I've got two data frames - Employee punch data and employee names data:

DF1

```
    punch_out punch_in date employee_number
 1  16:00:00  06:00:00 2018-01-01 00000001
 2  15:00:00  08:00:00 2018-08-01 00000001
```

DF2

```
employee_numb  job_title  start_date end_date
00000001        worker    2017-08-05 2018-07-01
00000001        manager   2018-07-01 3000-01-01
```

I need to join them so that in DF1 I would have a new column - "Job title" which will properly reflect the actual job title, according to the date.

My struggles are around the date conditions. So from the examples above: according to the example dates observation 1 should have job title "worker", but observation two has to have "manager".

If I do traditional join - it duplicates the records and I will have two rows for each DF1 row and employee 00000001 on 2018-01-01 will be both worker and manager.

The result should look like this

```
    punch_out punch_in date employee_number Job Title
 1  16:00:00  06:00:00 2018-01-01 00000001  worker
 2  15:00:00  08:00:00 2018-08-01 00000001  manager
```

Comment: Questions to the SO tag should have reproducible examples.  As it is we don't really know what you have.  To do that show the output of dput(DF1) and dput(DF2) in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqldf` package is one option here, which lets us phrase dataframe joins using SQL syntax:

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "SELECT Df1.punch_out, Df1.punch_in, Df1.date, Df1.employee_number, Df2.job_title
        FROM Df1
        LEFT JOIN Df2
            ON Df1.date BETWEEN Df2.start_date AND Df2.end_date"
result <- sqldf(sql)
```

Comment: I think you want this: `sql <- "SELECT a.*, b.job_title
        FROM DF1 a
        LEFT JOIN DF2 b
            ON a.employee_number = b.employee_numb and 
               a.date BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date"
sqldf(sql)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck `SELECT *` is generally evil, but using table aliases is fine.  I didn't use them, in this case, because the data frame names are very short.

Comment: Although I did improve the style in my opinion (but maybe not yours), the point of the comment was not the style but that (1) the sql code shown in the answer gives an error message. `no such column: df2.punch_in`   (2) Also even if that is fixed it needs to join on the employee as well and (3) the `coalesce` is not needed oir desirable since you will get a real ?NA without it rather than a string NA. (4) Also the data frame names are DF1 not df1 and similarly for DF2.

Comment: I am getting same mistake for both options: Error in match.fun(asfn) : 'c("as.hms", "as.difftime")' is not a function, character or symbol. I am pretty sure that my dates are dates and not strings. Still does not work.

Comment: Ensure your times are factor, character or chron times class.  Do not use POSIXlt or lubridate Period class.  These do not work well in data frames.  Please be sure to provide reproducible input in your question.

Comment: it seems to work without lubridate. Need to check though.

Answer (score 0):

Could also do:

```
library(data.table)

setkey(setDT(DF2)[, start_date := as.Date(start_date)], employee_numb, start_date)
setkey(setDT(DF1)[, date := as.Date(date)], employee_number, date)

DF2[DF1, roll = T, .(punch_out, punch_in, employee_number, job_title)]
```

If your columns are already dates, you can just do:

```
setkey(setDT(DF2), employee_numb, start_date)
setkey(setDT(DF1), employee_number, date)

DF2[DF1, roll = T, .(punch_out, punch_in, employee_number, job_title)]
```

The data used:

```
DF2 <- structure(list(employee_numb = c("00000001", "00000001"), job_title = structure(2:1, .Label = c("manager", 
                                                                                                       "worker"), class = "factor"), start_date = structure(c(17383, 
                                                                                                                                                              17713), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2018-07-01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "3000-01-01"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

DF1 <- structure(list(punch_out = structure(2:1, .Label = c("15:00:00", 
                                                            "16:00:00"), class = "factor"), punch_in = structure(1:2, .Label = c("06:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                 "08:00:00"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(17532, 17744
                                                                                                                                 ), class = "Date"), employee_number = c("00000001", "00000001"
                                                                                                                                 )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Getting bunch of NAs instead of result. 5639994:  23:06:00 19:00:00     1626092      <NA>

Comment: Check again. I assumed your columns are characters as you haven't provided a `dput` or previous code.

Comment: I pre-formatted them with ymd function before the join. job_title is obviously character. punchs are times (hms), empl_number is character too for both datasets.

Comment: the second setkey turns all employee numbers into NAs. that was the reason for the problem. Will look into it.

Comment: The code is fine, check with the data I added. If you provide the data in the same format with `dput` (few same observations), perhaps we can help with debugging, otherwise it'll be hard.